# Wordpress page not changed after I edit in dashboard editor

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I create a page for "Contact us" in my wordpress dashboard. The url is http://myurl/contactus. But the page is not shown at all. I checked the source code of the customized template which was not created by me. I found there is a file named page-contactus.php. But the contact page is still not shown after I deleted the page-contactus.php. Can anybody tell what could be the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used `page-contactus.php` then you need to select the `Template` from the dropdown to 'Contactus` to get the necessary customized template.

Moreover, when WordPress creates a page with `Contact us`, the slug is `http://myurl/contact-us`

Comment: Thanks. I know what you're saying. What I actually want is to use the default page template. But the page I just edited is not shown even after I delete the page-contactus.php.

Comment: There is no error message. The problem is whatever I added in dashboard editor is not shown. It seems the page did not get the content from the page edited in dashboard.

Comment: Check whether you have `page.php` and inside the file `the_content()`

Comment: OK, I'll check that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the_content() is the way.